# How to move point to front of an axis

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to create an animation of derivative. My problem is very simple: a point is hidden behind the x-axis.

This is my code:

```
f[x_] := (x - 3)^3 + 2 (x - 3)^2 + 3
h = 0.5
pontoa = {3, f[3]}
pontoax = {3, 0}
pontoh = {3 + 0.5 - h^(1/2), f[3 + 0.5 - h^(1/2)]}
pontohx = {3 + 0.5 - a^(1/2), 0}
pa = Graphics[{PointSize[0.013], RGBColor["#D00202"], Point[pontoa]}]
pax = Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], RGBColor["#D00202"], Point[pontoax]}]
ph = Graphics[{PointSize[0.013], White, Point[pontoh]}]
phx = Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], White, Point[pontohx]}]
tangente = Graphics[{Thick, RGBColor["#1CD176"], InfiniteLine[{pontoa, pontoh}]}]
traçoa = Graphics[{Dashed, Thick, RGBColor["#D00202"], Line[{pontoa, pontoax}]}]
traçoh = Graphics[{Dashed, Thick, White, Line[{pontoh, pontohx}]}]
plotset = {PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], RGBColor["#19A3CD"]}, AxesStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[0.003]], PlotRange -> {-0.2, 6}, Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, TicksStyle -> Directive[White, FontSize -> 14, FontColor -> White, FontFamily -> "Roman"], ImageSize -> 1000}
Show[funcao, tangente, traçoa, pa, pax, ph, phx, traçoh, Axes -> True, Evaluate@plotset]
```

After all, I will animate this variable h

This is the image that I'm generating:

[image]

See the red point in the x-axis. I want to move it to front. How can I do this?

Comment: see [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) in docs, it can be used with `Graphics` or `Show`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` in `Show`:

```
Show[funcao, tangente, traçoa, pa, pax, ph, phx, traçoh, 
  Axes -> True, Background -> Black, Evaluate @ plotset, 
  Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]